# Vanilla JS: How to get index of parent element with a certain class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

**In a nutshell**:

On click of a link below in the given HTML, I need to get the index of the parent with class "analytics". For example, clicking the link "myID2 Link 1" would return 1.

```
<ul id="myID1" class="analytics" data-attribute="hpg:shocking">
  <li><a href="http://myurl.com/">myID1 Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://myurl.com/">myID1 Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://myurl.com/">myID1 Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="myID2" class="analytics" data-attribute="hpg:expected">
  <li><a href="http://myurl.com/">myID2 Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://myurl.com/">myID2 Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://myurl.com/">myID2 Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="myID3" class="analytics" data-attribute="hpg:unexpected">
  <li><a href="http://myurl.com/">myID3 Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://myurl.com/">myID3 Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://myurl.com/">myID3 Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**What I've tried**:

I'm currently using two separate loops, one for iterating through the parents, the other for adding a click event to the links.

```
// helper function to check parent for a class
function hasParentWithClass(element, classname) {
  if (element.className.split(' ').indexOf(classname) >= 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return element.parentNode && hasParentWithClass(element.parentNode, classname);
}

// get all elements with class "analytics"
var analytics = document.querySelectorAll('.analytics');
var containerClass = [];

for (var z = 0; z < analytics.length; z++) {
  var inc = z + 1;
  containerClass.push(analytics[z].getAttribute('id'));
}

var links = analytics.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (hasParentWithClass(this, 'analytics')) {
    // output index of parent
    } else {
    // do nothing
    }
  }, false);
}
```

**The problem**:

I'm struggling with using the logic from the first loop inside the second loop. Specifically, searching var containerClass from within the second for loop to get the index of the parent, as it's stored in var containerClass. .indexOf did not serve me well.

What is the most straightforward, efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, the only permitted parent element for `<li>` elements are either `<ul>` or `<ol>` elements; and if you have an ancestor `<ul>`, or `<ol>`, element then they cannot contain a `<div>` element (unless that `<div>` is wrapped inside of an `<li>`).

Comment: My apologies, and thanks for the call-out. The HTML now has proper semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is much simpler than you think. If we assign a click event handler to the parent elements we can use event bubbling to solve the issue. When you click a link, it will not only trigger the `click` event for the link you clicked, but that event will "bubble" up through the ancestor elements of that link as well. If we capture the event at the parent, we can just get its index.

Also, as @Dave Thomas points out, your HTML structure for your list(s) is not valid.

```js
// Get all the .analytics elements
var analytics = document.querySelectorAll(".analytics");

// Loop through them
Array.prototype.slice.call(analytics).forEach(function(item, index, arry){

  // Set up click event handlers for each of the parents
  item.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    // Just access the index of the parent within the group
    console.clear();
    console.log("The index of the parent is: " +  index)
    
    // Now, display the index of the link within its parent .analytics element
    
    // Get all the anchors in the current analytics container
    var anchors = Array.prototype.slice.call(item.querySelectorAll("a"));
    
    // Get the index of the anchor within the set of anchors
    var idx = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(anchors, evt.target);
    console.log("The index of the link within the parent is: " + idx);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="myID1" class="analytics" data-attribute="hpg:shocking">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">myID1 Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">myID1 Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">myID1 Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="myID2" class="analytics" data-attribute="hpg:expected">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">myID2 Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">myID2 Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">myID2 Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="myID3" class="analytics" data-attribute="hpg:unexpected">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">myID3 Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">myID3 Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">myID3 Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. What if I also wanted to get the index of the clicked link within its own parent? I.e., clicking "myID1 Link 3" would return an index of "2".

Comment: @asw1984 See the comments in my updated answer for a solution on this.

Comment: Great stuff @Scott Marcus. One more question: I noticed you're chaining .parentNode to work your way up to the parent element from the link. Is there a more generic approach, for a scenario where the parent with class "analytics" isn't 2 levels up from the child link, but some other number, say 4 or 6.

Comment: @asw1984 Updated answer to do just that.

Comment: So I simplified the HTML structure for this example, but in reality there are also some child elements inside the anchors. This is causing the click to bind to the deepest element. Is there a way to ensure it always binds to the anchor click?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const index = Array.from(item.parentNode.children).indexOf((item))
        console.log(index);
    })
})
```